# Non-linear Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this equation 
$$y'' = 8yy', y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 1$$ 
$$v = y'$$
$$v' = 8y v$$
$$ \frac 1v dv = 8y dy $$
$$ ln(v) = 4y^2 + c $$
$$ v(0) = 1 => ln(1) = 0 + c <=> c = 0$$
$$ ln(v) = 4y^2$$
$$ v = e^{4y^2} $$
$$ v = y' => y'= e^{4y^2}$$
Now Wolfram Alpha tells me the solution is $y = \frac 12 tan(2x)$ and so I am stuck as I am getting a different answer when I solve this. Could anyone guide me? Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Just integrate once in the original equation to find
$$
y'=4y^2+C
$$
which then can be solved via separation for all the signs of $C$.

---

For your approach in seeking solutions in the form $y'=v(y)$ you need to correctly apply the chain rule in $y''=v'(y)y'=v'(y)v(y)$ to find that
$$
v'v = 8yv.
$$

Comment: Thankyou, I solved it correctly!